# Does it make sense to create a WAR anymore?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is more specific to spring boot projects and applications whose main USP is its APIs. Now that we can simply create a JAR file deploy it anywhere, what is the point of WARs? Is there a specific use cases where we require a WAR type file? In a normal maven project, or a normal java project, yes sure. But in Spring boot projects, why would we ever package an application with APIs as a WAR?

**Edit:** By JAR, I mean executable JARs and not libraries.

Comment: I feel like StackOverflow would be more suitable for this, since this seems more related to technology (Java plus Spring Boot), rather than software engineering concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends entirely on what your Ops setup is. Many organizations have an established operations department with procedures and ways of doing things, and they have their app servers and know how to administrate them. In that scenario, it makes sense to simply produce a WAR and let them deal with it instead of establishing new procedures for Spring Boot JARs.